# Error C2511 - overloaded member function not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

In the code sample below, class Die is just a base class that AttackDie inherits. When AttackDie is instantiated, it needs data stored in an instance of class StatSys and an integer value. As a result, the constructor for AttackDie has been designed to take an instance of StatSys and a integer as inputs. However, the compiler is throwing a C2511 error on the line containing `AttackDie::AttackDie(StatSys * LocalSystem, int Type)`
The error is as follows:

AttackDie::AttackDie(StatSys *,int)': overloaded member function not found in 'AttackDie

I don't understand why this error is showing up. I've checked the header and source. The declaration and implementation interfaces both seem to match. Could someone direct me to the problem?

Code Samples

Dice.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <Dice.h>
#include <StatisticsSystem.h>

using namespace std;

AttackDie::AttackDie(StatSys * LocalSystem, int Type)
{
    DataIntegrity = true;

    if (Type > -1)
    {
        switch (Type)
        {
        case 0:
            DieType = "Red";
            DieClass = "Damage";
            break;

        case 1:
            DieType = "Green";
            DieClass = "Balanced";
            break;

        case 2:
            DieType = "Blue";
            DieClass = "Accuracy";
            break;

        case 3:
            DieType = "Yellow";
            DieClass = "Surge";
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Unrecognized TypeNum value (>). Initialization of key AttackDie variables failed./n";
            DieType = "Error";
            DieClass = "Error";
            DataIntegrity = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unrecognized TypeNum value (<). Initialization of key AttackDie variables failed./n";
        DieType = "Error";
        DieClass = "Error";
        DataIntegrity = false;
    }

    if (DataIntegrity)
    {
        const int GROUP_SIZE = 3;
        int Iterator = 0;

        int Test[3];
        bool CSVDataValid = true;
        for (int OuterCounter = 0; OuterCounter <= LocalSystem->NUM_OF_SIDES - 1; OuterCounter++)
        {
            Test[0] = LocalSystem->AccessCSVData(Type, Iterator);
            Test[1] = LocalSystem->AccessCSVData(Type, Iterator + 1);
            Test[2] = LocalSystem->AccessCSVData(Type, Iterator + 2);
            Iterator += GROUP_SIZE;
            if (Test[0] <= -1 || Test[1] <= -1 || Test[2] <= -1)
            {
                CSVDataValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Sides[OuterCounter].Damage = Test[0];
                Sides[OuterCounter].Surges = Test[1];
                Sides[OuterCounter].Accuracy = Test[2];
            }
        }
        if (!CSVDataValid)
        {
            cout << "Side specific parameters were not set. CSV data not valid.";
            DataIntegrity = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Total = { 0, 0, 0 };
            for (int SideCounter = 0; SideCounter <= 5; SideCounter++)
            {
                Total.Damage += Sides[SideCounter].Damage;
                Total.Surges += Sides[SideCounter].Surges;
                Total.Accuracy += Sides[SideCounter].Accuracy;
            }
            Averages.Damage = Total.Damage / LocalSystem->NUM_OF_SIDES;
            Averages.Surges = Total.Surges / LocalSystem->NUM_OF_SIDES;
            Averages.Accuracy = Total.Accuracy / LocalSystem->NUM_OF_SIDES;
        }
    }
}
```

Dice.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

struct AttackStatAverages
{
    double Damage;
    double Surges;
    double Accuracy;
};

struct DefenseStatAverages
{
    double Blocks;
    double Evades;
    int Dodges;
};

class Die
{
public:
    string GetDieType();
    string GetDieClass();


protected:
    string DieType;
    string DieClass;
    bool DataIntegrity;
};


class AttackDie : public Die
{
public:
    AttackDie(StatSys * LocalSystem, int Type);
    int GetSides(int SideNum, int Parameter);
    double GetAverages(int Parameter);
    int GetTotal(int Parameter);
    ~AttackDie();

private:
    AttackStats Sides[6];
    AttackStatAverages Averages;
    AttackStats Total;
};
```

StatisticsSystem.h

```
    #pragma once
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <Dice.h>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    struct DicePackage
    {
        int Mode;
        int Quantity;
        int NumberOfPossibilities;
        bool Error;
        AttackDie* AttackDice[4];
        DefenseDie* DefenseDice[3];
    };

    class StatSys
    {
        friend class AttackDie;
        friend class DefenseDie;
    public:
        StatSys();
        ~StatSys();
        const double VERSION = 0.1;
        int AccessCSVData(int Row, int Column);

    private:
        static const int MAX_NUM_OF_DICE = 4;
        const int METHOD_ERROR_SIZE = 10;
        const int NUM_OF_SIDES = 6;
        const int GROUP_SIZE = 3;
        const int DAMAGE = 0;
        const int SURGES = 1;
        const int ACCURACY = 2;
        const int BLOCKS = 0;
        const int EVADES = 1;
        const int DODGE = 2;
        const int ITERATIONS = 3;
        DicePackage DiceSet;
        bool CSVDataState;
        bool ErrorDataState;
        int CSVData[6][18];
        vector<string> Errors;
        vector<string> ErrorDescriptions;
        int StringToInt(string Value);
        void LoadCSV();
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem along with the verbatim error messages (emphasis on ***minimal***).

Comment: Seconding the request for MCVE. Too much code AND incomplete. Any stabs I take at sorting this out change the code and may remove your problem.

Comment: Off topic: fault in Dice.h. It doesn't `#include <StatisticsSystem.h>`. This forces an undocumented extra dependency or ordering of the includes on anyone including Dice.h.

Comment: Turns out that's not so off topic. I think you're building against stale objects or not building Dice.cpp at all. Do a Build->Clean Solution and then build again and make sure Dice.cpp is not being left out.

Comment: I just reduced the code to the bits referenced in the explanation, added snippets of StatisticSystem.h to give a more complete picture of the problem, and more clearly isolated the verbatim error in an attempt to better provide an MCVE. @user4581301, I must've missed that include statement. I'll add that in. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Looks like that did the trick. Thanks @user4581301!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <Dice.h>
#include <StatisticsSystem.h>
```

should be

```
#include "Dice.h"
#include "StatisticsSystem.h"
```

<> is primarily for system headers

"" are for header files in the same directory

Comment: Not a good answer because it doesn't address OP's problem. Would be a good comment though.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that detail. I'll make the change. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I edited it to also have StatisticsSystem.h. Before I didn't realize that was a custom file.

Comment: Where is `AttackStats` declared? I see it referenced in Dice.h, but I can't tell how it is declared in that scope.

Comment: My guess is that it is declared in the AttackDie class which Dice.h knows nothing about. That is why it needs StatisticsSystem.h included. So that the friend declarations would be there. You could try making Total a pointer to an AttackStats object and just forward declaring the class. Not sure because we are not seeing the full picture. It looks like some code is missing to me.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't have enough rep to comment on other people's answers yet. ;( just starting trying to help today.

Comment: @user4581301 since the problem to me seems like it had to do with includes I hoped making the change I recommended would help alleviate all or part of the problem

Comment: @JoelBirlingmair That's why I didn't downvote your answer. It would put you further from making useful comments.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like user4581301 was correct. Adding `#include <StatisticsSystem.h>` to Dice.h fixed the issue since Dice.h does in fact need data from that header.